# Interpreting boxplot VS stacked histogram in example

Tags: inference, interpretation, boxplot

I understand what a boxplot and histogram are supposed to show, but I'm a bit confused on how it is being presented in this graphic printout from R. The picture is taken from  *Beyond Multiple
Linear Regression* by Roback and Legler.

The response variable under study is horse's speed. In the exploratory part of this activity we have the following set of plots. The ones circled I'm having trouble interpreting. `Year` as a variable is self explanatory, the `condition` variable is a categorical variable with three levels. The data is the speed of the winning horse of the Kentucky derby for each year.

In looking at the boxplot the $X$ - axis is the `year` and the $Y$ - axis is the track `condition`. Implicitly I do get that the boxplot is showing the median speed at each track condition, but that is not being conveyed in terms of the labelling. When looking at the labelling I would gather that the "median" year is what is being captured by the boxplot. But that doesn't make much sense in this context. Am I missing something in what I'm looking at? because I don't see how you can have median year for an event having one occurrence each year.

The graphic I'm discussing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When looking at the labelling I would gather that the "median" year is what is being captured by the boxplot.

That's correct, that's what is being displayed by the median line -- but not only the median, since the boxplot includes other information.

> But that doesn't make much sense in this context.

When you plot all variables against all other variables, certainly some of those plots may not make much sense. However, the fact that the typical year seems to change with condition does tell you something; this is quite clear in the histograms. We see that the first condition is relatively more common recently than it was, by contrast with the other two conditions, which mostly appear in the earlier years. The median year by condition tells you something of this same effect.

Comment: So in the boxplot form it is serving as some sort of "count". Where the notion only makes sense if I am comparing each of the boxplots to one another. i.e: "condition A has occurred more frequently than condition B and C based on these median values in the boxplots".

Comment: "*condition A has occurred more frequently than condition B and C based on these median values in the boxplots*" --- no, that's not what it tells you. The median value is *YEAR* not frequency. You need to read carefully.